# Spectrochemical Series - Latest version?

Tags: erratum, crystal-field-theory

--Studying the Crystal Field Theory [under Coordination Chem.] at school now--

A book my teacher lent me [printed in 2002] has the spectrochemical series in it, and it depicts pyridine [py] as having the *same* 'strength' as ammonia. But a bunch of other sources [including Wikipedia] display the spectrochemical series albeit it depicts ammonia as having *greater* 'strength' than pyridine.

Since I have serious trust-issues with Wikipedia, and since that book I mentioned is fairly old, could someone tell me the latest version of the spectrochemical series? Also could you cite a reliable source?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you cite both sources you find contradicting?

Comment: @Lucademicus Unfortunately, that's going to be a little difficult. That book my teacher lent me was issued by the college he studied at for B.Sc chem students, you won't find it in the open market.....the title doesn't really stand out ['Inorganic Chemistry'] so I don't think that helps....